# Creating a new column in pandas dataframe as a function of another column

Tags: python, pandas

My pandas dataframe has an existing column, "div", which has a string.  I want to make a new column ('newcol') whose value equals the first character of the string in div.

I've tried to specify this several ways but it doesn't work.

`results['newcol'] = results['div']`  gives me the full string (as expected) not the first char.

`results['newcol'] = results['Div'].values[0]` and `results['newcol'] = results['Div'][0]`
makes the newcol in  every row equal to the 'Div' string of the first row.

`results['newcol'] = str(results['Div'])` and `results['newcol'] = str(results['Div'])[0]`
convert the entire ['Div']series into a single string and returns that to newcol.

What's the correct way to specify what I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["hello", "world"], "B": [1, 2]})
data["C"] = data.A.str[0]
data
```

This is the output:

```
  |   A   | B | C 
------------------
0 | hello | 1 | h
------------------
1 | world | 2 | w
```